# Run job based on Cronjob spec in Openshift Web Console

Tags: openshift

I'm very much aware of this --from flag:

```
oc create job test-job --from=cronjob/a-cronjob
```

However, is there such a feature in the Webconsole of Openshift (vers. 4.13)?
... where I don't need to copy/paste the spec from the cronjob resource.